# execute keyup once

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

I'm trying to load a gif loader when I start to type in a textbox. I'm appending it to the div that contains the textbox on keyup. The problem I have is that the loader is appended every time I type a letter while I would like to append it only once when I type the first letter.

```
function loader(){

    $('#contrib_search').bind('keyup', function(){
        $('#contrib_text').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
    });
}
```

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: why dont you have the loader `display: none` by default and then swap class on keypress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can unbind the keyup after you add the loader

```
function loader(){

    $('#contrib_search').bind('keyup', function(){
        $('#contrib_text').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
        $('#contrib_search').unbind('keyup');  //or $(this).unbind probably a tad faster
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using '**one**' could help:

```
function loader() {
  $('#contrib_search').one('keyup', function () {
    $('#contrib_text').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to hardcode loader into your HTML code and then `.show()` it on `.keyup()` event handler.

Then for example in `.blur()` event `.hide()` it and the problem is gone.

Edit:

```
var $contrib = $('#contrib_text');

$contrib.bind({
    keyup: function(){
       $contrib.find("#loader").show();
    },
    blur: function(){
       $contrib.find("#loader").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could work :

```
var pressed = false;
    function loader(){

        $('#contrib_search').bind('keyup', function(){
            if (pressed == false ){
                $('#contrib_text').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
                pressed = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

or instead of using this boolean just call unbind instead of my line saying pressed = true;